# Data in different columns with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    C.RazonSocial AS 'Contratista',
    C.Cuit,
    CTO.Numero AS 'Contrato',
    S.Codigo as 'Codigo Sociedad',
    S.Descripcion AS 'Sociedad',
    CTO.FechaInicio AS 'Fecha Inicio',
    CTO.VigenciaHasta AS 'Fecha Fin',
    CER.FechaInicio AS 'Fecha Inicio Exepcion',
    CER.FechaFin AS 'Fecha Fin Excepcion',
    CPPC.Porcentaje
FROM
    ContratosExcepcionesRetencion AS CER
INNER JOIN 
    Contratistas AS C ON C.Id = CER.ContratistaId
INNER JOIN 
    Contratos AS CTO ON CTO.ContratistaId = C.Id
INNER JOIN 
    Sociedads AS S ON S.Id = CTO.SociedadId
INNER JOIN 
    ContratoPeriodoPorcentajeCumplimiento AS CPPC ON CPPC.ContratoId = CTO.Id
INNER JOIN 
    Periodos AS PER ON PER.Id = CPPC.PeriodoId
WHERE
    PER.Fecha < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) AND 
    PER.Fecha > DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE()) AND
    CTO.Numero = '4900074911'
GROUP BY 
    C.RazonSocial,
    C.Cuit,
    CTO.Numero,
    S.Codigo,
    S.Descripcion,
    CTO.FechaInicio,
    CTO.VigenciaHasta,
    CER.FechaInicio,
    CER.FechaFin,
    CPPC.Porcentaje
```

With the following results:

{[image: Result]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJmPc.png)

but I want the following result:

[image: desired result]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: instead of Grouping by CPPC.Porcentaje remove it from there and write `MAX(CPPC.Porcentaje)`

Comment: If I use max it will only show me a single CPPC.Porcentaje and I need all three but in different columns

Comment: Can you describe in text what you want/need?  Those (unreadable) screendumps make someone guess at what you need/want

Comment: I want the CPPC.PORCENTAJE column to be displayed in 3 different columns but grouping the rest of the data that are the same, instead of the result being 3 lines I want it in only 1 since the only different data is the CPPC.PORCENTAJE column. Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language. Thank you!